# Instance controlling using enum

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a factory class, which I have made singleton using enum. I want to make sure that the object being created is also singleton (Please note that I do not own the class being created, but I want to ensure that it's object is singleton).

I am trying something like this

```
public enum MyFactoryImpl implements MyFactory {
    INSTANCE;
    private final MyObject myObject = buildMyObject(); //I want to instance control this

    private MyObject buildMyObject() {

         return new MyObject();
    }

    public MyObject myFactoryMethod() {
        return this.myObject;   
    }
}
```

I tried calling the factoryMethod in a test case in parallel fashion using testNG, and multiple invocation seem to return the same hashCode.

```
@Test(threadPoolSize = 10, invocationCount = 600, timeOut = 100000)
public void test_instanceControlledBehavior() {
    final MyFactory f1 = MyFactoryImpl.INSTANCE;
    final MyFactory f2 = MyFactoryImpl.INSTANCE;
    Assert.assertEquals(f1.myFactoryMethod().hashCode(), f2.myFactoryMethod().hashCode()); 
}
```

Is this the correct way of implementing the behavior? Is there a better way I can instance control 'MyObject'?

Comment: That will certainly work. You should use `==` instead of `hashCode()` to check for reference equality though.

Comment: If you have no control over the class being instantiated, how can you prevent the user from doing his own `new MyObject()`?

Comment: Building on what @RealSkeptic said:  Using the enum pattern makes it impossible for some other programmer to create more instances of your MyFactoryImpl class (assuming that the other programmer can not change your source code), but you have done nothing to prevent that other programmer from writing his own methods that call `new MyObject()`.

Comment: ...But why prevent a programmer from doing what works?  Paul Graham (http://www.paulgraham.com/) once said something like, Surely a library that allows a programmer to do X is _at least_ as powerful as one that forces the programmer to do X.

Comment: All you will be able to guarantee is that all invocations of `MyFactoryImpl.myFactoryMethod()` return the same object. If you want to prevent multiple instantiations for `MyObject` you'll have to modify `MyObject` (private constructor, static factory method). This can be done using instrumentation or a custom classloader and something like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/), but I'm guessing this is too far-fetched?

Comment: Singleton management can be more complicated in a multithreaded case, you can read up on [double checked locking][1] as a starting point to understanding that problem.

[1] http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/05/double-checked-locking-on-singleton-in-java.html

Comment: I do not want to prevent any user from doing his own 'MyObject'. RealSkeptic and jameslarge are correct that infact I can't even accomplish this using this code. However, in my own code, I want the object creation to be encapsulated behind a factory and want to re-use the same object. Custom loader and other approached mentioned by Kenney can definitely be avoided here.